# Knockoutjs: Populate dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, knockout.js

I have the following dropdowns with select multiple attribute that I need to convert them into normal dropdowns, keeping their functionality:
From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]
[image]

Here are  the select dropdowns with the bindings:

```
<select data-bind="click: $root.divisionddupdate, foreach: Products, updateDDPlugin: true" id="divisiondd" multiple="multiple" >
    <option data-bind="value: ID, text: Name"></option>
</select
<select data-bind="click: $root.companiesddupdate, foreach: Partners, updateDDPlugin: true" id="companiesdd" multiple="multiple">
    <option data-bind="value: ID, text: Name"></option>
</select>
```

The dropdowns are initially populated from the foreach and on clicking an option, the other dropdown populates accordingly.
 
I removed the "multiple" attribute, but:
**Q:** How can I modify my code so that I could have the first option as "Select" (even after update) and the options from the other dropdown could be updated on option change, not on option click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`options`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) binding, that's what it's there for. Be sure to set the `optionsCaption`, `optionsText` and `optionsValue` as well as a `value` binding.

It will render as a select dropdown with an initial `Select` option set and will display the `Name` property of each product.  It will use the `ID` property to set as the selected value, `SelectedProduct`.

```html
<select data-bind="options: Products,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select',
                   optionsText: 'Name',
                   optionsValue: 'ID',
                   value: SelectedProduct">
</select>
<select data-bind="options: Partners,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select',
                   optionsText: 'Name',
                   optionsValue: 'ID'
                   value: SelectedPartner">
</select>
```

If you needed cascading dropdowns, make your `Partners` dependent on the `SelectedProduct` and filter your options through a [dependent (`computed`) observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).